# Control directive reporting "A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods"

Tags: asp.net, ascx

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET project and I have a control who's source page, currently, has no markup and just a control directive:

```
<%@Control language="C#" CodeFile="SummaryEventFeed.ascx.cs" Inherits="SummaryEventFeedControl"%>
```

When I build (using msbuild or Visual Studio) it points to that line and says:

> Error 240 A namespace does not
>   directly contain members such as
>   fields or methods

There's obviously no namespace here, so the error message is quite puzzling.  The codefile also doesn't specify a namespace - it's just a public partial class.

Ideas welcome.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing the namespace name to the control which you are inheriting from, like so -

```
Inherits="yournamespace.SummaryEventFeedControl"%>
```